# Two forms on the same page drupal

Tags: drupal-6, drupal-forms

I have a database of clients. Before entering a new client, I want to make sure that that client is not already in the database. So I want to put a search form at the top of my page to search by client number, and client name. Further down the page, I'll have another form to enter and submit the client's information. Would this be the best way to go about something like this? How would you approach this? i'm using drupal 6.

Comment: Is this for you convenience alone or part of some feature you want others to use as well? That is, are you manually entering client information, and you just want the ease of being able to point and click look up if a client exists?

Comment: This is not just for convenience. I'm building a client management system. It's basically a database for storing clients/persons. I just don't want to enter the same client twice, because different people will be doing the data entry and the clients will be numerous.

Comment: Are you asking for a module you are writing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better that when the user is inserting a new customer name, an autocomplete shows the names matching the characters inserted by the user; if the user wrote "Mic", and in the database there is a customer with the name "Michael Greenpeace", the autocomplete will show "Michael Greenpeace", and the user will understand there is already a record for that customer.

Even without the autocomplete (which would help the user to understand if the data for the customer has been already inserted in the database, and continue with the next customer), a user that inserted the name of an existing customer should see the existing data; this would help the user to avoid rewriting data that are already updated (customer information need to be updated, sometimes, and not only inserted).

Comment: Thanks Kiamlaluno...I have actually decided to put the search lookup for clients on another page, then list the results with a link to edit them. Thanks for your response though...appreciated